# Remove all text occurrences in PDF using itext

Tags: itext7

I want to remove all text from a PDF using iText7.
So far, I was able to use PDFCleanUp, but it draws a colored box over the text and thus alters the background.
I want to fully remove pure text objects (i.e., Pdfname.text), so that only remains in the PDF everything but it.

Thanks

I am attaching now the original and clean images

[image]

[image]

Comment: By "text" you mean what is drawn by "text showing instructions"? Or do you also mean scanned text?

Comment: I mean, actual rendered text (i.e., no glyphs or images posing as text) objects (ASCII or any type of encoding). Thus, scanned text would not apply.

Comment: Please attach the code you have so far and describe your current result vs expected result in a more visual way - this will help more people to understand your question and give you the answer you expect

Comment: I actually managed to do it using itext7's, PdfCleaner.AutoSweepCleanUp, and with null as redaction color. However, the speed is terrible. I think there should be a faster solution.